# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter is less accessible than method *LINE 35*

Tags: c#

Inconsistent accessibility: parameter is less accessible than method *LINE 35*
I cant figure out for the life of me whats wrong, I have a feeling something is private when it should be public, but I cant find it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace Hangman
{
    public partial class Hangman : Form
    {
        public Hangman()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string word = string.Empty;
        List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
        private int amount;

        enum BodyParts
        {
            Head,
            Body,
            Right_Arm,
            Left_Arm,
            Right_Leg,
            Left_Leg
        }

        void DrawBodyPart(BodyParts bp)
        {
            Graphics g = manPanel.CreateGraphics();
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);

            if(bp == BodyParts.Head)
            {
                g.DrawEllipse(p, 40, 50, 40, 40);
            }
            else if (bp == BodyParts.Body)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, new Point(60, 90), new Point(60, 170));
            }
            else if (bp == BodyParts.Right_Arm)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, new Point(60, 100), new Point(90, 85));
            }
            else if (bp == BodyParts.Left_Arm)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, new Point(60, 100), new Point(30, 85));
            }
            else if (bp == BodyParts.Right_Leg)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, new Point(60, 170), new Point(90, 190));
            }
            else if (bp == BodyParts.Left_Leg)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, new Point(60, 170), new Point(30, 190));
            }
        }

        void DrawHangPost()
        {
            Graphics g = manPanel.CreateGraphics();
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Brown, 10);

            g.DrawLine(p, new Point(130, 218), new Point(130, 5));
            g.DrawLine(p, new Point(135, 5), new Point(65, 5));
            g.DrawLine(p, new Point(60, 0), new Point(60, 50));
        }

        void MakeLabels()
        {
            word = GetRandomWord();
            char[] chars = word.ToCharArray();
            int between = 330 / chars.Length - 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length - 1; i++ )
            {
                labels.Add(new Label());
                labels[i].Location = new Point((i * between) + 10, 80);
                labels[i].Text = "_";
                labels[i].Parent = labelsGroupBox;
                labels[i].BringToFront();
                labels[i].CreateControl();
            }

            label1.Text += (chars.Length - 1).ToString();
        }

        string GetRandomWord()
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string wordlist = wc.DownloadString("http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt");
            string[] words = wordlist.Split('\n');
            Random rand = new Random();
            return words[rand.Next(0, words.Length - 1)];
        }

        void ResetGame()
        {
            Graphics g = manPanel.CreateGraphics();
            g.Clear(manPanel.BackColor);
            GetRandomWord();
            MakeLabels();
            DrawHangPost();
            missedLabel.Text = "";
            guessesLabel.Text = "";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawHangPost();
            MakeLabels();

            Button[] buttons = new Button[] { buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, buttonD, buttonE, buttonF, 
            buttonG, buttonH, buttonI, buttonJ, buttonK, buttonL, buttonM, buttonN, buttonO, buttonP, 
            buttonQ, buttonR, buttonS, buttonT, buttonU, buttonV, buttonW, buttonX, buttonY, buttonZ, };
            foreach (Button btn in buttons)
            {
                //common code for all the buttons:
                btn.Click += new EventHandler(buttons_Click);
            }
        }

        private void buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            char letter = button.Text.ToLower().ToCharArray()[0];

          /*  if (!char.IsLetter(letter))
            {
                button.Enabled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Only letters.");
                return;
            } */
            if (word.Contains(letter))
            {
                char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (letters[i] == letter)
                    {
                        labels[i].Text = letter.ToString();
                    }
                }

                foreach(Label label1 in labels)
                {
                    if (label1.Text == "_") return;
                    MessageBox.Show("You Won!");
                    ResetGame();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                missedLabel.Text += letter.ToString() + ", ";
                DrawBodyPart((BodyParts)amount);
                amount++;
                if (amount == 6)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You lost. The word was: " + word);
                    ResetGame();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The line is: void DrawBodyPart(BodyParts bp)

Comment: Default accessor for a method is private, so I can't find out what's wrong, did you try specifing private accessor for the DrawBodyPart method?

Comment: I tried both public void DrawBodyPart(BodyParts bp) AND private void DrawBodyPart(BodyParts bp)

Comment: is there something wrong with my call in 
            else
            {
                missedLabel.Text += letter.ToString() + ", ";
                DrawBodyPart((BodyParts)amount); ?

Comment: No, if the method DrawBodyPart is defined private, then there is no way that a "parameter is less accessible" error occurs for the method. That's really weird, did you try rebuilding the solution and/or reopening visual studio?

Comment: Just re opened Visual Studio and it seems to work properly. Thank you. Cutting it off and back on again should have been the first thing I tried. lol.

Answer (score 0):

if u didn't provide access modifier to method signature default it will be private so if you are trying to access outside the class it will show accessibility error.. you need to change the access modifier from default to public.

Note : if you are trying to call this method inside the class it won't be a problem else you need to change the access modifier!!

Comment: I changed it to " public void DrawBodyPart(BodyParts bp) " but I still seem to get the error when i call for it in the "  else
            {
                missedLabel.Text += letter.ToString() + ", ";
                DrawBodyPart((BodyParts)amount); "

Comment: does now also problem exist?

Comment: I changed all the methods to public, the only things that are private now are the Form1_load, and the buttons_Click